# Remove all lines that contain characters other than

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a list of with words and unwanted characters

```
hag-lawig
ha
waray
katapusan
/
¤
8¨2Þ‹%·/ój
An
ngatanan
nga
makakita
ha
akon
```

I want to remove all lines that contain characters other than a certain string of characters; in my case "a-z" and "-".
That is, in this case, lines containing "ó" "A" "%" etc. should be removed:

```
hag-lawig
ha
waray
katapusan
ngatanan
nga
makakita
ha
akon
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*[^a-z-].*$\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    .*      # 0 or more any character but newline
    [^a-z-] # any character that is not lowercase or dash
    .*
$           # end of line
\R?         # any kind of linebreak, optional
```

**Result for given example:**

```
hag-lawig
ha
waray
katapusan
ngatanan
nga
makakita
ha
akon
```